# Inequality involving product of numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Show that if $a,b,c$, and $d$ are positive numbers such that if $a+b = c+d = 10$ and $a$ and $b$ are farther apart than $c$ and $d$, then $ab < cd$.

The hint says, '$ab = a(10-a)$ and $cd = c(10-c)$. So, try graphing $y = x(10-x)$.'

I graphed the quadratic but can not see how to progress further. Specifically, I can not see how to use the 'farther apart' part of the problem.

If possible, please answer using the hint.

Comment: Did you not notice that the closer $x$ (and $10-x$) get to five, the bigger $y$ gets?

Comment: Aha! I see it now. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm... what I'd do is relabel them as $a = 5-k; b=5+k$ (we don't know whether $k$ is pos or neg) and $c = 5-h; d=5+h$.  "$a$ and $b$ are farther apart than $c$ and $d$" would therefore mean $|k| > |h|$.  We need to prove that $(5-k)(5+k) < (5-h)(5+h)$ when $|k| > |h|$ and .... well, it solves itself, doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

You know... I'd ignore the hint and give a different hint of: As they add to $10$ they must average $5$; re-express them relative to $5$.

> That is:  Let $a$ be off from $5$ by $k$.  That is $a = 5+k$ (Note: we don't know is $a$ is less or more than $5$ so we don't know if $k$ is positive or negative but it doesn't matter.  We could WOLOG $k>0$ but we don't actually have to.  Then $b=10-a =5-k$.  Likewise Let $c = 5+j$ and $d= 5-j$.

Then the statement " a and b are farther apart than c and d" means simply

> $|a-b| = |(5+k) - (5-k)| = 2|k| > |c-d| =|(5+j) - (5-j)|=2|j|$ and so $|k| > |j|$.

Now proving $ab <cd$ is just a matter of proving:

> If $|k| > |j|$ then $ab =(5+k)(5-k)< (5+j)(5-k) = cd$

and that solves itself!

> If $|k| > |j|$ then $ab = (5+k)(5-k) =25 - k^2$ and $cd=(5+j)(5-j)= 25 - j^2$ and as $|k| > |j|$ then $k^2 > j^2$ and $25-k^2 < 25 - j^2$.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume $\,a,,b,c,d\in\mathbb{N},\,$ one would think there are only 4 cases to be tested because of the restriction that $\,b-a>d-c.$

\begin{cases}
\begin{align*} 
(a,b,c,d)\,\,(b-a,d-c)&\implies ab<cd\\
(1,9,2,8)\quad (8\quad,\quad6)&\implies 9<16\\
(2,8,3,7)\quad (6\quad,\quad4)&\implies 16<21\\
(3,7,4,6)\quad (4\quad,\quad2)&\implies 21<24\\
(4,6,5,5)\quad (2\quad,\quad0)&\implies 24<25
  \end{align*}
\end{cases}

For integers, all case are true. It would be different if we removed the requirement that
$\,a+b=c+d=10.$ For example
$\quad (7,3,1,2)\implies21\not\lt2.$